# DatePickerFragment is giving me an error

Tags: android, datepicker

Added this in `onCreate()`. Found this as an answer to a question regarding datepickers.

```
    final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                              int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            updateLabel();
        }

    };

    edittext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new DatePickerDialog(classname.this, date, myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
        }

    });
```

and outside `onCreate()` I put

```
 private void updateLabel() {
    String myFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"; //In which you need put here
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY");

    edittext.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
}
```

But the `classname.this` is showing an error and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: what is your activity/fragment's name?

Comment: replace `classname.this` to `yourActivty/fragmentname.this`.

Comment: what is classname.this?

Comment: i added all the code in the mainactivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DatePickerDialog requires a context as first parameter in its contructor.

If this is inside a fragment, use getActivity() instead of classname.this.

If it's in an activity you could declare a global Context variable set it to 'this' in onCreate() and use it instead of classname.this.